# Query to select 'Customer_Num' with digit characters using regular expression

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, regular-expression

I have a table with below structure:

```
Example_table(Customer_Num    varchar2(50))
```

Some Example data in this table :

```
        Example_table
----------------------------
        Customer_Num
           12445
           12345
           12ttd
           2376y
           23%%*
           23467
```

I want to select custoemr_num records with digit characters , so these records `12ttd , 2376y , 23%%*`
should not appear in the final result . Considering the fact that I can not change the table structure , which one is the correct query ?

```
Q-1:
  select customer_num
  from Example_table 
  where REGEXP_LIKE(customer_num, '[[:digit:]]')


Q-2:
  select customer_num
  from Example_table 
  where REGEXP_LIKE(customer_num, '[0-9]')
```

Are there any special condition in which these queries might end up producing wrong results?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is correct because both only check for a single digit that can appear anywhere in the string.

A regex that **only** selects digits in the complete string would be:

```
where REGEXP_LIKE(customer_num, '^[0-9]+$')
```

- `^` anchors the expression at the beginning of the string (to avoid leading non-digits)
- `[0-9]+` matches multiple digits but at least one
- `$` anchors the expression at the end of the string (to avoid trailing non-digits)

There is no difference between using `[0-9]` and using `[[:digit:]]`